# Change Colors and Using Setting Up an API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, highcharts

I am trying to use highcharts on my rails webapp. I am completely new to this. How would I change the color of the down candle sticks to red and the up candle sticks to green?

This is what I have:

```js
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length,
            // set the allowed units for data grouping
            groupingUnits = [[
                'week',                         // unit name
                [1]                             // allowed multiples
            ], [
                'month',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ]],

            i = 0;

        for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ]);
        }


        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Historical'
            },

            yAxis: [{
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'OHLC'
                },
                height: '60%',
                lineWidth: 2
            }, {
                labels: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -3
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Volume'
                },
                top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 2
            }],

            series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

If I load: http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=? I can figure out what all of the numbers are expect for the first one, what does that represent? The date somehow?

How could I, using rails, make a JSON for highcharts to use so that I could see the the updates per minute.

---

**My Questions:**

- How can I change the color of the candlesticks?
- How do I make an API that this code can fetch to show a candlestick for every minute of the year?
- How can I update this code to show minute candlesticks instead of daily candlesticks?

Thank you very much.

Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change colors use [`color`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.candlestick.color) and [`upColor`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.candlestick.upColor).

I'm not Rails dev, but to answer other questions:

- in JS use `setInterval()` to get data by AJAX from the backend
- for minute-based candlesticks, simply provide data which has timestamp every minute. In the example, data is daily based.

Regarding data format: `[1222646400000,17.09,17.10,14.37,15.04,655513663]`

First one is timestamp in milliseconds, next four values are open-high-low-close and the last one is volume used for the second pane.

I strongly recommend to read tutorials:

- [data from database in PHP](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-from-a-database)
- [live data](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data)

I'm pretty sure generating JSON in Rails can't be hard.